# I am getting a error causing my app to crash

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, pojo

**NotesListActivity.java**

```
package com.example.notes;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
 import android.nfc.Tag;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import com.example.notes.Adapters.NotesRecyclerAdapter;
 import com.example.notes.Models.Note;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class NotesListActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
private static final String TAG = "NotesListActivity";
//UI COMPONENTS
private RecyclerView mrecyclerview;

//VARIABLE SECTION
private ArrayList<Note> mNotes=new ArrayList<>();
private NotesRecyclerAdapter mNotesRecylerAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_list);
   mrecyclerview=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    initRecyclerView();
    fakeNotes();

}

private void fakeNotes() //method to populate reccylerview for testing
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        Note note=new Note();
        note.setTitle("Title#"+i);
        note.setContent("content #"+i);
        note.setTimestamp(" jan 2019");
        mNotes.add(note);
    }
    mNotesRecylerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
private  void initRecyclerView()
{
    LinearLayoutManager linerlayoutmanager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linerlayoutmanager);
    mNotesRecylerAdapter=new NotesRecyclerAdapter(mNotes);
    mrecyclerview.setAdapter(mNotesRecylerAdapter);

 }
 }
```

**NotesRecyclerAdapter.java**   (Adapter)

```
package com.example.notes.Adapters;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.notes.Models.Note;
import com.example.notes.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NotesRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
 private ArrayList<Note> mNotes=new ArrayList<>();

 public NotesRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<Note> mNotes)
 {
     this.mNotes = mNotes;
 }

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view=
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_notes_list_item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.timestamp.setText(mNotes.get(position).getTimestamp());
    holder.title.setText(mNotes.get(position).getTitle());
 }

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return mNotes.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    TextView title, timestamp;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        title =itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        timestamp=itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_timestamp);
    }
  }
```

}

**activity_notes_list.xml**   (Recycler view)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".NotesListActivity">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="5dp">
```

**layout_notes_list_item.xml  (layout of recycler view)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/darkYellow"
android:weightSum="100"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
>
<view
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_title"
    android:text="This is my first note"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="75"
    android:lines="1"/>
<view
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_timestamp"
    android:text="12jan2019"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="23sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:lines="1"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

**Note.java**

```
  package com.example.notes.Models;
  public class Note
  {
  private String title;
  private String content;
  private String timestamp;

  public Note(String title, String content, String timestamp)
  {
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
  }

  public Note()
  { }

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title)
{
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent()
{
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Note{" +
            "title='" + title + '\'' +
            ", content='" + content + '\'' +
            ", timestamp='" + timestamp + '\'' +
            '}';
  }
  }
```

**ERROR THAT  I AM GETTING AND APP IS CRASHING DUE TO IT!**
I am learning android now and i have crossed checked the source code even but cant find any differences.

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.notes, PID: 2846
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
 java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
  java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at 
   com.example.notes.Adapters.NotesRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NotesRecyclerAdapter.java:31)
    at 
    com.example.notes.Adapters.NotesRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NotesRecyclerAdapter.java:15)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
    at 

    androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline
    (RecyclerView.jaVa:5975)
     at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
    at 
    androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
    at 
    androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1791)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1635)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1544)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:758)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:19590)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6053)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
    Application terminated.
```

Comment: `Binary XML file line #11: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean` what is line no 11

Comment: What is the "view". Can it be "View"?

Answer (score 2):

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Attempt to
>   invoke virtual method 'boolean

Your Tag should be **`<View.`** Not `<view`

```
<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkGrey"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```